# AlpineLinux PXE boot specify startup script as kernel parameter

Tags: alpine-linux, ipxe

Is there a way to specify a script as kernel parameter during pxe boot? I want run a bunch of computers as workers. I want them to use PXE to boot AlpineLinux and then run a bash script that will load my app and join my cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Change dir:

```bash
cd /tmp
```

Create directory structure:

```
.
└── etc
    ├── init.d
    │   └── local.stop
    └── runlevels
        └── default
            └── local.stop -> /etc/init.d/local.stop
```

```bash
mkdir -p ./etc/{init.d,runlevels/default}/
```

Create file `./etc/init.d/local.stop`:

```bash
#!/sbin/openrc-run

start () {
    wget http://172.16.11.8/rickroll/video.mp4 -O /root/video.mp4
}
```

```bash
chmod +x ./etc/init.d/local.stop
```

```
cd /tmp/etc/runlevels/default
```

Make symlink:

```bash
ln -s /etc/init.d/local.stop local.stop
```

Go back:

```bash
cd /tmp
```

Create archive:

```bash
tar -czvf alpine-test-01.tar.gz ./etc/
```

Make pxelinux (on your tftp server) menu:

```
label insatll-alpine
    menu label Install Alpine Linux [test]
    kernel alpine-installer/boot/vmlinuz-lts
    initrd alpine-installer/boot/initramfs-lts
    append ip=dhcp alpine_repo=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/main modloop=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/releases/x86_64/netboot/modloop-lts modules=loop,squashfs,sd-mod,usb-storage apkovl=http://{YOUR_WEBSERVER}/{YOUR_DIR}/alpine-test-01.tar.gz
```

And run:

[image]

My webserver log:

```
10.10.15.43 172.16.11.8 - [27/Aug/2021:01:15:22 +0300] "GET /rickroll/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 5853379 "-" "Wget"
```